# Swipe to refreshlyout with Recycler and expandable listview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, swiperefreshlayout

I have to create one screen which includes two lists 
1) Recyclerview
2) expandable listview

When Recycler is Visible then i have to hide expandable list and when expandable list visible i want to hide Recyclerview. Everything is working fine. but i have some confusion i need to add swipe to refresh layout for both lists, how can i achieve these ? My problem is when there is no data in recycler view and expandable list swipe to refresh isn't working as expected . Any one have suggestions what should i do now?

Comment: yes facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use cache to store the data which is used in recyclerview and expandable list view formerly and then try refreshing the cache.

Comment: when both RecyclerView and Expandable listview have empty data then Swipe to Refresh isn't working.

Comment: Are you using sql-server and json parsing to get the data into RecyclerView and Expandable listview.

Comment: @karrthikdatabase what is relation with server and json with swipe to refresh view ? why you are asking such questions ?

Comment: check this out http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/

Comment: to that above i have done some manipulations so that your RecyclerView will not be null. And ofcourse the the above example doesnot say anything about RecyclerVIew.